# Javascript order of execution in setInterval

Tags: javascript, execution

Suppose i am running some code inside a setInterval. That is, a bunch of code is begin run every 33ms or so.

Inside this bunch of code is a function, lets call it the Overlord function, which executes other functions depending the values of some state variables.

The question is this:

Suppose Overlord executes function1. Suppse that function1 has not finished running after 33ms (or whatever the interval length is) . Then Overlord executes function2 while function1 is presumably still running. What happens?

Does function1 finish before javascript runs function2? Is there some sort of que built into javascript execution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded, so the second function will be queued, but cannot be executed until the first has finished executing. That said, if your function takes more than 33ms to execute, it might be a good idea to break it into small asynchronous chunks (in order to prevent locking up the interface).

Answer (score 2):

This is where `setInterval` can quickly become a ***REALLY BAD IDEA***™ .

The problem is this:

If you call `setInterval(lots_O_functions, 15);` what's going to happen is that `lots_O_functions` is going to get called 15ms later, BUT if it takes, say 45ms to finish doing all of that work, it's not going to be interrupted, instead you're going to have two more `lots_O_functions` calls waiting to run as soon as your first one is done...

...assuming that those two ALSO take 45ms apiece, you now have 6 more `lots_O_functions` calls waiting in line...

Is that what you want to happen?  I don't know.  Personally, I'd say it's not, the majority of the time, and here's why:

JS runs on a single thread.  In fact, pretty much ***EVERYTHING*** in the browser (clicks, repainting the elements on the page, even leaving the page and going somewhere else) are all tied to the same thread in the VAST majority of cases.

So clogging that thread up with overlapping calls to heavy functions is ***NOT GOOD***™

Instead, why not have something like:

```
var big_state_machine = { /*...*/ },
    lots_O_work = function () {
        big_state_machine.currentState.jobs.forEach(/*...*/);
        /*....... do lots o' work ......*/
        var more_work_to_do = /* figure out if you need to rerun lots_O_work */;

        if (more_work_to_do) { setTimeout(lots_O_work, 20); }
    };


lots_O_work();
```

Now, it's going to do what it needs to do, and if it's got more to do afterwards, it's going to call setTimeout to queue itself a ***minimum*** of 20ms after that point.

`setTimeout` isn't like a `sleep` or a `wait`, it says: "Look 20ms into the future, to see how many people are already waiting to do things...  ...starting there, put me in the next available spot in line".

The difference here is that you're getting that done 20ms after your first function is finished, which means at least 20ms for other things to happen (clicks, painting, AJAX, etc).

With `setInterval`, it's like `setTimeout`, but instead of queueing up in the next available spot *after* the fact, it sets itself in the queue, whether it's ready (or needed) or not.

You can go even further into breaking this up to keep it really responsive, but this would be a good start.

Comment: JS can see into the future?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes.  With its JS time-goggles.  That's Google's side-project, which is already complete in an alternate-fork of our current reality.  It really IS that good.  In marginally more-serious tone, I much prefer "see into the future" rather than "queue a callback which will be processed a minimum of `Math.max(requested_ms, browser_min_step_ms);` from the time the request is made, or placed on the heap of requests to be executed, otherwise".

Comment: And by "placed on the heap of requests to be executed, otherwise", for sake of pedantry, I do mean that it will schedule itself to be put on the heap at that time, and as such, competes with any other async requests which are intended to be inserted at the same time, plus any requests which are queuing up due to synchronous events, interim, which is exactly why relying on something like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to act as a clock or as a frame-limiter (or the expectation of keeping a steady frame-rate), is misguided, among other niggling details like depending on specific race outcomes.

Comment: Interesting! I dont think ill need this idea this time, but its in my bank :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threaded, so you are safe.... most of the time. The only way function2 will run before function1 is complete is if function1 has any asynchronous code with callbacks to finish like ajax calls or another setTimeout or setInterval. For example:

```
var setInterval(function(){

    //.. 
    function1();
    function2();

}, 33);

var globalVariable = 0;

var function1 = function(){
    console.log(globalVariable);

    setTimeout(function(){
        globalVariable+=2;
    }, 1000);
};
var function2 = function(){
    console.log(globalVariable);
};
```

The output for this program would be.

-->0

-->0

-->2

-->2

And you may have expected.

-->0

-->2

-->2

-->4